# Documenting an DApp components

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, javascript, ipfs

I am new to building decentralized applications and i am trying to document the process of building an DApp.

Waht are the components as well as installations that are needed to build An Dapp ?
(if is compulsory to use Embark, Solidity and IPFS what are the other needed components and installations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basics Steps:

1. Write Smart Contract (Solidity)
2. Deploy Smart Contract to the blockchain - You can use remix or truffle for this.
3. Write your frontend code utilizing Web3.js to call functions on your contract.

Now if you aren't familiar with Remix, Truffle or Web3 - I would recommend checking out the documentation.

Comment: Do you have a full stack development background?  You will have to read the docs for truffle or watch some tutorials on remix.   Remix is a browser based IDE - that allows you to write, debug and deploy your smart contract Ethereum or a test Ethereum blockchain.   https://remix.ethereum.org/    After you you deploy you contract you will get an ethereum address for you smart contract.  Web3.js is a Javascript library that allows you to build your front end and connect to your smart contracts address. https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/

Comment: Id recommend going through the Crypto Zombies tutorial to learn more about solidity and web3.js    https://cryptozombies.io/      I found this to be a fun and easy way to learn everything.